# how to remove a group tr with a given class name using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a given group of tr in a table that I need remove based on a class name of group. My way is not working...

```
    $("table tr").each(function()
    {
          $(this).hasClass('group').remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table tr").each(function)
```

should instead be:

```
$("table tr").each(function ()
```

---

On further inspection, the code should be

```
$("table tr").each(function () {
    if( $(this).hasClass('group') )
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's  slight error in your code

```
$("table tr").each(function()
    {
          if($(this).hasClass('group'))
              $(this).remove();
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dkRmB/)

---

[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns boolean true if set of elements are having class specified in param. If not it'll return false. So you need to apply a condition check and then do the action.

Answer (score 0):

please try,  this should work

```
$("tr").each(function()
{
     if($(this).hasClass('group'))
        $(this).remove();
});
```